# How to reset a frame rate in IQualProp::get_AvgFrameRate?

Tags: c++, rendering, directshow

I get an average frame rate from the EVR renderer using the IQualProp::get_AvgFrameRate method. It worked well but after call of Pause/Run in the DirectShow graph I got wrong values of frame rate. Here some my solutions:

1. Standard solution:

   bool Pause() 
   {
   IMediaControl* pMediaControl;
   pMediaControl->Pause();
   }

   bool Run() 
   {
   IMediaControl* pMediaControl;
   pMediaControl->Run();
   }

After pMediaControl->Run() the renderer shows me the frame rate values in two times less  than it is necessary. But during 10-15 sec those values are restored.

2. Via Stop() method:

   bool Pause() 
   {
   IMediaControl* pMediaControl;
    pMediaControl->Stop();
   pMediaControl->Pause();
   }

   bool Run() 
   {
   IMediaControl* pMediaControl;
   pMediaControl->Run();
   }

Into the Pause() I add pMediaControl->Stop(). After Run() I get the right frame rate but the renderer freezes for 10-15 sec.

3. Using IMediaFilter::Run()

   bool Pause() 
   {
   IMediaControl* pMediaControl;
    pMediaControl->Stop();
   pMediaControl->Pause();
   }

   bool Run() 
   {
   IMediaFilter* pMediaFilter;
   pMediaFilter->Run(1000000); //delay 10ms
   }

Here I got the nice result without freezing and wrong values. But CPU utilization is more in two times than before Pause().

Ideas?

I can return to my old schema, when I got an average frame rate by calculation of frames, but I would like to use the  IQualProp::get_AvgFrameRate method.

Comment: I don't think it's meant to be resettable. It's an informational metric without promised accuracy, and you do see it gets properly re-adjusted after pause/run cycle. You will need a custom presenter if you need accurate numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I returned to the old schema.  Rewrite the code of getting average FPS is better than the rework of three  source filters